# Jolt map field existence to boolean field

Tags: json, jolt

I need a jolt spec that maps the existence of "kind" field in input, to a boolean field in the output

INPUT:

```json
{
  "payload": {
    "device_id": "99cbf1618f87",
    "kind": "event"
   }
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```json
{
   "device_id": "99cbf1618f87",
   "has_kind": true
}
```

---

INPUT:

```json
{
  "payload": {
    "device_id": "99cbf1618f87"
   }
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```json
{
   "device_id": "99cbf1618f87",
   "has_kind": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use default operation, to introduce the kind field, where it does not exists. Then shift the values.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        /* 
         * introduce the kind node, where kind does not exists
         * Use the value that will not come as a part of the kind
         * kind node in original json. In this spec, "notexists"
         * is used
         */
        "kind": "notexists"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "device_id": "device_id",
        "kind": {
          /*
           * If kind has the value notexists then set the has_kind
           * to false, else set the has_kind to true
           */
          "notexists": {
            "#false": "has_kind"
          },
          "*": {
            "#true": "has_kind"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jagadesh ! but this approach leaves the boolean as String in the output. Should I add an extra modify operation using the =toBoolean function? or is there a simpler way to achieve that?